# Iframe with webplayer: Uncaught ReferenceError: BrowserDetect is not defined

Tags: iframe

I have an iframe and the first page that i load in this iframe is responsive and works properly.

[image]

When i click a link within iframe it opens an other cdn page with a webplayer iframe on it and i get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: BrowserDetect is not defined for a webplayer.iframe

This causes the webplayer not to be responsive.

[image]

Is there anyway i can help through iframe configuration the webplayer to detect my browser?

HTML5 video is height: 100%; width: 100%; so normally should be responsive.

I have no access to the iframe content and they are not from the same domain. Thnx